# substring of a column from another SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following table.

```
+--------------------+-----+
|fardet_cd_fare_basis|part2|    
+--------------------+-----+
|            MEO00RIG|  00R|
|            MEO00RIG|  RIG|
|            MEO00RIG|    I|
+--------------------+-----+
```

I need to extract from "fartdet_cd_fare_basis" the first part of the chain until the appearance of "part2", an example would be:

```
+--------------------+-----+--------+
|fardet_cd_fare_basis|part2|     num|
+--------------------+-----+--------+
|            MEO00RIG|  00R|     MEO|
|            MEO00RIG|  RIG|   MEO00|
|            MEO00RIG|    I| MEO00RI|
+--------------------+-----+--------+
```

I'm working with Spark SQL, but I used the sql solution. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you explain the expected output again properly? It is hard to understand. And do you need only 1 row in output for the sample data? If yes then what is the logic and if no, then what and why should be the output of other rows.

Comment: It is understood better now?

Comment: I answered just now. If it worked for you, then accept the answer so the question could be closed.

Comment: Root cause: 1NF violation. Symptom: can't write what should be a simple query, instead having to split a single attribute into sub atomic parts at run-time. Fix: change the design e.g. tokenize the attribute into multiple new attributes. Benefit of the doubt: you are carrying out a one-off exercise to fix your design :)

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you want. Try this.

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/35995/10)**</kbd>

```
select fardet_cd_fare_basis,part2,
  substr(
           fardet_cd_fare_basis,
            1,
            instr(fardet_cd_fare_basis,part2)-1
         ) as der_sub
from your_table
```

Output

```
+----------------------+--------+---------+
| fardet_cd_fare_basis | part2  | der_sub |
+----------------------+--------+---------+
| MEO00RIG             | (null) | (null)  |
| MEO00RIG             | O      | ME      |
| MEO00RIG             | 00R    | MEO     |
| MEO00RIG             | RIG    | MEO00   |
| MEO00RIG             | 00     | MEO     |
| MEO00RIG             | I      | MEO00R  |
| MEO00RIG             | R      | MEO00   |
| MEO00RIG             | 00     | MEO     |
+----------------------+--------+---------+
```

Note: If `part2` doesn't exists in first column, the you will not get anything in output. Also if `part2` is null then you would get `null`. You can handle them separately if you want.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try if possible to implement this response sql spark . If anyone knows how to do it ...